CefGlue example not working for Ubuntu-24.04
I am trying to run CefGlue on Ubuntu from https://github.com/OutSystems/CefGlue/tree/main
I am able to build it on Ubuntu. But I am not able to run a Sampe Example.
using System;
using Xilium.CefGlue;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var mainArgs = new CefMainArgs(args);
            var app = new cefApp();

            CefRuntime.Load();
            Console.WriteLine("Log for youtube.com");
            var settings = new CefSettings
            {

                MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true,
                LogSeverity = CefLogSeverity.Default,
                LogFile = "reddit_cef.log",

                RootCachePath = "C:\\RootCachePath",
                CachePath = "C:\\RootCachePath\\CachePath",
                //  ResourcesDirPath = "",
                //  LocalesDirPath = ""

            };



            CefRuntime.Initialize(mainArgs, settings, app, IntPtr.Zero);

            var windowInfo = CefWindowInfo.Create();
            windowInfo.SetAsPopup(IntPtr.Zero, "CefGlue Example");

            var browserSettings = new CefBrowserSettings();
            var client = new cefClient();

            CefBrowserHost.CreateBrowser(windowInfo, client, browserSettings, "https://www.reddit.com");

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            CefRuntime.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    class cefApp : CefApp
    {
    }

    class cefClient : CefClient
    {
    }
}

This Works fine on Windows but the same code with changes in RootCachePath and CachePath I am not able to run it on Ubuntu (I have downloaded and putted the binaries of Cef of linux in the Bin folder).
 sudo dotnet run
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008
[1229/063202.488366:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(155)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x8007000E
[1229/063202.514815:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(155)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008.

This is the Error I am getting on a Loop.

This question is similar to: .NET 8 Microsoft Docker Image: Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070008. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
